# Jquery trigger event appends content but DOM not ready after

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling with something that i think would be simple. I know that i've had the same problem in plain old javascript without JQuery before. What i try to do is:

```
//When the postal code blurs, lookup the city, country, province
$('#codePostal').blur(function(){
    $.get('/fr/radio-telethon/ajax_code_postal.php', {code_postal: $('#codePostal').val()}, function(data){
        if(data.code_postal.toLowerCase() == $('#codePostal').val().toLowerCase()){
            $('#ville').val(data.ville);
            $('#pays').val(data.pays);
            $('#pays').trigger('change');
            $('#province').val(data.province);
            $('#province').trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

This basically calls a postalcode lookup script and returns an object with the data. The data itself is correct, i can alert it and it shows fine. The problem is that the change trigger on #pays (country in english) reloads the information inside #province (state) and it seems like the DOM is strugling and not loading the info.

If i alert between the the trigger on the country and the val on the province, i can set the province correctly. The method i use to add provinces to the province box is the following:

```
//Empty the provinces
$('#province').empty();

//Get the new data
$.get('/include/radio-telethon/formulaire-ajax.php', {pays: code}, function(data){

    //Loop the items
    for(i in data.options){
        $('#province').append('<option value="'+data.options[i].value+'">'+data.options[i].label+'</option>');
    }

    //Setup the label
    $('#labelProvince').html(data.label);

});
```

So my guess is that APPEND is messing up everything and making the whole DOM linger and thats why i can't seem to do $('#province').val(data.province);

Is it me? Or is there a magic trick i can't seem to find...

Comment: Oh and i also tried to do $('#province').ready(function(){ $(this).val(data.province); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Jasper, i found a more than applicable solution to my problem so i'll thumbs up Jasper for his solution but i'll mark mine as the answer.

What i used is that i passed the data.province to the extraParameters of the trigger and added a

```
//When country changes, show/hide the province/region
$('#pays').change(function(event, province){

    ........ other code .......

    //If there is a province in the parameter, set it
    if(province !== 'undefined'){
        $('#province').val(province);
        $('#province').trigger('change');
    }


    ........ other code .......

});
```

in the #pays.change handler using:

```
$('#pays').trigger('change', data.province);
```

This way, i don't create a global variable like Jasper did and i can still detect if the trigger of the change event passed in a province or not.

Thanks Jasper

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event handler for the `#pays` element includes an AJAX call which is asynchronous. So it probably won't return before the code just below runs. A good fix would be to run this code:

```
        $('#province').val(data.province);
        $('#province').trigger('change');
```

In the callback for your `$.get()` call:

```
//setup a variable to store the province once it's returned from the server
var province = '';
$('#codePostal').blur(function(){
    $.get('/fr/radio-telethon/ajax_code_postal.php', {code_postal: $('#codePostal').val()}, function(data){
        if(data.code_postal.toLowerCase() == $('#codePostal').val().toLowerCase()){
            $('#ville').val(data.ville);
            $('#pays').val(data.pays);
            $('#pays').trigger('change');

            //save the province so it can be used later
            province = data.province;
        }
    });
});

//Get the new data
$.get('/include/radio-telethon/formulaire-ajax.php', {pays: code}, function(data){

    //Loop the items
    for(i in data.options){
        $('#province').append('<option value="'+data.options[i].value+'">'+data.options[i].label+'</option>');
    }

    //Setup the label
    $('#labelProvince').html(data.label);

    //update the #province element using the saved province variable
    $('#province').val(province).trigger('change');
});
```

Your code can take advantage of some optimization as well:

```
var province = '';
$('#codePostal').blur(function(){
    var thisValue = this.value;//cache `this.value` since it's used multiple times
    $.get('/fr/radio-telethon/ajax_code_postal.php', {code_postal: thisValue}, function(data){
        if(data.code_postal.toLowerCase() == thisValue.toLowerCase()){
            $('#ville').val(data.ville);
            $('#pays').val(data.pays).trigger('change');//notice the function chaining
            province = data.province;
        }
    });
});
$('#pays').change(function () {

    //Get the new data
    $.get('/include/radio-telethon/formulaire-ajax.php', {pays: code}, function(data){
        var output = [];

        //Loop the items, using a much faster loop, also buffering the output so it gets added to the DOM at once which creates A LOT less overhead

        for(var i = 0, len = data.options.length; i < len; i++){
            output.push('<option value="'+data.options[i].value+'">'+data.options[i].label+'</option>');
        }

        //this will empty the #province element and append the output at once
        $('#province').html(output.join('')).val(province).trigger('change');

        //Setup the label
        $('#labelProvince').html(data.label);

    });
});
```

Here is a JSPerf to show the performance increase in the loop I used just above: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Comment: @gdoron Thanks for the edit, but it removed a paragraph I wrote, so I rolled-it-back.

Comment: Ohhh! I'm sorry!!! But you can still indent the code right... =) Didn't read the answer, but get my +1...

Comment: Thanks for the perf tests on the foreach, i'll take that in consideration for the future. Right now i have only 13 elements in general so it's not really slowing off but with larger arrays i'll definitely keep that in mind